# How to create a memory flash virtually via USB for an external device?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, serial-port, usb

I'm working on a project in which I want to make a virtual USB flash memory via my USB port for an external device, for example, a satellite receiver that needs a memory for recording TV channels. I want to connect the PC USB port to the satellite USB port and record files directly to a file. I'm working in C#/.NET.

Comment: Not possible. The USB controller in your PC is hardwired to act as host and (probably) in your device as well.
Maybe with a special cable, but it's not simply done by software.

Comment: Thanks, Do you think is it possible with a usb to serial convertor cable? I think I must implement Flash Memory protocol via serial port, but where to find its protocol? I mean where to find something like documentation about flash memory protocol? or something like a library to work with serial port as a memory? (Excuse me for delay to response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB Protocol is generally between two distinct devices: The *host* and the *client*. The host says what data gets transferred and when, the client has to listen. Then there are different **device classes** for clients. There are USB removable media, printer, webcam ans others. USB otg differs slightly as a device can be client or host depending on the other one. For example your mobile phone van be client when connected to a PC or host wehn it's connected to a USB stick.

Now there is your satellite receiver. It wants to be host. (You know that when it uses the big Type-A socket) And it expects a removable media device like a USB stick. When you connect a printer it will not know what to to with it. Same with a network adapter or serial port.

> N.B.: You cannot possibly implement "Flash Memory protocol via serial port". Because Serial Port is already the client device class. Also, there is no wire compatibility between USB and serial.

As your PC is in the same role and will not act as client in the USB connection, there is no simple solution. (I bet you knew this already, huh?)

Even if you got a PCIexpress card that acted like a flash drive, there would be more hurdles. For example file systems are not designed to be accessed by two computers simultaneously.

Back to constructive answering:
[Inspired from this link](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/dev/199189) you could grab some higher end microcontroller and attach a (micro)SD card. Then you let it act as a flash drive on its USB port. Use its Ethernet connection (or wifi for that matter) and provide access to the (micro)SD card via samba.

This is some really high end stuff for a microprocessor, so better not use the very cheap ones. RasberryPI Model A (not the B one, that cannot act as a USB client) or Arduino/Netduino (the most powerful) came to my mind.
I could not find a ready-to-use device.

The important thing is, that the connection to you PC uses some kind of networking and not USB. Because networking protocols have the concurrency (multiple PCs accessing the same data) covered whereas local file systems don't.

Comment: MegaTons of Thanks DasKrümelmonster, I think im gonna starting a very grate work, hope to have a nice result.